# Need single activity in new task backstack

Tags: android, android-activity, task, back-stack

It is nightmare when must deal with android task and launching modes(flags).

Need accomplish this scenario:

From background service launch Activity[1] that belongs to App[A] in new task.
When user go [back] - finish activity[1] and resume whatever App was previously in foreground!

If App[A] was active and running - there is no problem, [beck] close Activity[1] and resume App[A].
But if any other App[B] is in foreground at the moment when launching Activity[1] (even with the new Task) all App[A] tasks and stacks came forward over App[B] and broke [back] navigation.
I suppose to see App[B] after navigating back from Activity[1].

Tried several flag combination, but none of them accomplish what needed.

Suitable only when App[A] running:

```
                Intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
                Intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ExcludeFromRecents);
```

Suitable only when App[B] running (clears App[A] backstack):

```
                Intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask);
                Intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ExcludeFromRecents);
```

How to configure Intent to launch only one independed Activity[1] and go back to resume whatever was previously on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` flag will do

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
```

Comment: Indeed, it did, by why docs are so strictly against it? `Do not use this flag unless you are implementing your own top-level application launcher. Because the default system does not include graphical task management, you should not use this flag unless you provide some way for a user to return back to the tasks you have launched.` What is graphical task management? And of course i do not implement top-level application launcher for that particular dialog activity.

Comment: One has to dig deep into the source code to understand what the doc really says, which I haven't. I use this flag in a different scenario before. Say you have a button in an activity that pressing this button  will instruct a service to do work and launch a phone call. If launching the phone call with the ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK flag, the activity which is visible and in the foreground (the one which own the button) will not be brought back to the foreground when the phone call terminates. Instead the dial screen is the one that become visible.

Comment: Thanks for this - I had a slightly different issue, where invoking a known other app via a URL filter brought it into my app's back-stack, whereas I wanted to create a new task with its own history. `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` did the job!