# Launching an Activity from the background without attaching it to the task stack of existing activities of the same app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, background, launch

I am launching an activity A from a service in the background, this works well and the activity is created and usable with the code below:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, getActivityClass());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

This however has an unwanted behaviour if there is already a running activity B of the app containing activity A in the task list.
The user would expect to get back to the activity that was in the front when my activity A was started from the background if he uses the back button,
however it navigates back to activity B instead which really is confusing.

After reading docs I tried to allow task reparenting which did not work and still shows the problem described above.

```
    <activity
        android:name="net.x.y.z.PickContactActivity"
        android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    </activity>
```

According to this question [Need single activity in new task backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513352/need-single-activity-in-new-task-backstack)  the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK should be used, however it is mentioned in the comments on this to not use it unless implementing an app-launcher

> Do not use this flag unless you are implementing your own top-level application launcher. Because the default system does not include graphical task management, you should not use this flag unless you provide some way for a user to return back to the tasks you have launched.

What do I then have to do to fix this? In short: the pick contact activity should simply be handled as a real new task without being associated with any other running instance of the app, just as i would open notepad two times on a windows pc

I'd really be glad to have good solution on this,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BY DEFAULT;two activities from the same app will appear in the same task;to change this behaviour add this in the Manifest xml for the activities A and B: android:taskAffinity="";and change android:allowTaskReparenting to "false"